# How can i make the images stored in s3 be specific to my use?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, amazon-s3, paperclip

I used paperclip gem and i stored the images in amazon s3. And then i click on the image and copied the address of the image and i tried opening in another window and it displays the images. So ultimately anybody can access the images and thereby making number of hits in s3 will increase. How can i make the images specifically for my use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything is explained [here](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/wiki/Restricting-Access-to-Objects-Stored-on-Amazon-S3).

Comment: I have set :s3_permissions => :private but still i can access the image using url

Comment: I guess the picture was uploaded before you did this

Comment: oh yes. OK i will try new one

Comment: I tried and now the image is not even displayed in my app but the image is loaded in s3.

Comment: Sure, you now have to follow all steps from the link I provided